# How do I order the content of a mysql table by any field with php?

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

Basically, I have a MySQL database, and in it I have a table called "games", I figured out how to display all the games in the table using PHP, as you can see here:

http://rawgameshop.com/index/all/

Basically this is what it does:

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo $row['Name']."<br />";
   echo $row['Price']."<br />";
   echo $row['Stock']."<br />";
   echo $row['Platform']."<br />";
   }
```

The table in the database is sorted by the "Names" value. What I want to accomplish is that I sort it by the "Price" value, descending from e.g. 9.99, so that I can use the "Games under €9.99" button on my front page.

Comment: You can change the sql while taking data from the database to get the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's your SQL Query? You could just add `ORDER BY` clause to it.

```
SELECT * from games ORDER BY Price DESC
```

And for all games under 9.99, you could do

```
SELECT * from games where Price < 10 ORDER BY Price DESC
```

Comment: Cheers, take 10. No Rush :)

Comment: This is the solution, thank you very much. I am not very experienced with PHP... bare with me.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the part where you create your query. But your query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM games
WHERE price < 10 ORDER BY price DESC
```

In PHP:

```
if (result = mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM games WHERE price < 10 ORDER BY price DESC')) {
    //print out all games here
    result->close();
}
```

Comment: Please fix the function name. Its `mysqli`, not `mysql`